# Preserve figure caption sequence when inserting new captions in Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word-2013

Here is the problem.  I have all of the figure captions in a word document, and then I go to add another figure caption but the numbering continues to reflect the total number of figures in the document rather than the relative position of the caption.  This problem is not fixed by simply changing the number in the figure caption dialogue because in the table of figures the auto-numbering prevails.

Is there a solution to this problem?

For example:

Figure 1
Figure 2
<---------*
Figure 3
Figure 4
Figure 5

- When I go to insert caption here it is automatically numbered as Figure 6 (reflecting total number of figures in document, rather than Figure 3 which is what it should be.

Comment: Have you tried updating field codes? (Press Ctrl+A to select all, and then press F9.)